# Smalltalk web app deployment on headless Linux server

Tags: smalltalk, seaside, pharo

We wrote a small prototype web app using Pharo and Seaside and we want to now demonstrate to the suits that the app can be deployed into our standard Linux build. We use a mix of CentOS, Ubuntu Server and Gentoo which are run headless since most of our apps are JAVA/Apache based. Only port 80 and 443 are open to the outside world.

What are your experiences when hosting Seaside/Smalltalk server side apps?

Answer (score 2):

I just use a ssh tunnel to get the X display on my local machine. I'm using slicehost (US) from the Netherlands, so I have a ping time of 135 ms. That's not that nice, but ok.

Next step will be Lukas Renggli's remote frame buffer package to use a vnc viewer.

Let's see what Miguel Cobá had to say about it on it on the Gemstone mailing list:

> If you have already installed a RFB in your machine then use it.
>   If you have RFB installed in your image and it is accesible from your
>   client machine, use it
>
> But, both of them are unencrypted. If you want to encrypted you must
>   setup a tunnel (maybe with ssh or maybe TLS).
>
> I think that that is redundant because you must use a tunnel and then
>   the RFB. So what I do, in linux is to install the minimal X libraries
>   and then forward the X session to my local machine.
>
> In the server (Debian/Ubuntu instructions):
>
> aptitude update
>
> aptitude install xbase-clients
>
> aptitude install xtightvncviewer
>
> Test it from the client machine:
>
> ssh -X remote_server
>   squeakvm gemtools.image &
>
> This will start the squeakvm process on the server, but all the graphics
>   will be shown on the local machine (the Xserver for this particular
>   scenario).
>
> Also, if you install RFB on some of your images and start them headless,
>   you can use xtightvncviewer to connect to inside the image through the
>   RFB server.
>
> ssh -X remote_server
>   xtightvncviewer localhost:0 &
>
> this will run the xtightvncviewer on the remote server but, again, will
>   show on your local machine. Supposing you have your image in the remote
>   server running RFB in the first display.
>
> Which is the advantage:
>   - You don't have to open ports for RFB on the remote server
>   - You transmit everything encrypted through ssh
>   - You only run the commands on demand in the remote server. You don't
>   have to have VNC running always.
>   - You can configure your RFB in the image to accept only localhost
>   connections and not from everywhere.

Martin McClure adviced me to take a look at NoMachines NX (less chatty X),
but that's still on my todo list.

For another set of deployment instructions, take a look at [Miguels](http://miguel.leugim.com.mx/) blog

Comment: Does this mean that your local box is up 24x7? maybe something like screen along with the ssh tunnel is an option??

Answer (score 2):

it runs great, btw you can get free hosting for your seaside app at:

http://www.seasidehosting.st/

for more power you'd need your own server of course...

some benchmarks here:

http://gemstonesoup.wordpress.com/2007/10/19/scaling-seaside-with-gemstones/

Answer (score 2):

The [Seaside Book](http://book.seaside.st/book/) has a chapter on [deployment](http://book.seaside.st/book/advanced/deployment/deployment-apache). It describes how I typically deploy a Seaside application.

Answer (score 0):

The blogosphere's been talking about this issue recently.

[Doug Putnam](http://smalltalkthegoodparts.com/?p=17) wrote up his experiences in installing Seaside (on Pharo) on his Slicehost slice, working off [James Robertson](http://www.jarober.com/blog/blogView?showComments=true&printTitle=Getting_this_Server_Running&entry=3439652561)'s writeup (which uses VisualWorks, I suppose?).